# How to put a scrollbar on top of a table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table which is pretty wide to be fully shown on normal monitors. Is there a way to imply a scrollbar on top of the table (or the container `div`?) [Like in discourse users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJSo.png).

**HTML**

```
<div id="table_div">
    <table id="myTable">
       //content goes here           
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#table_div {
overflow-x: auto;
float: left;
width: 90%;
margin-left: 5%;
}

#myTable {
height: auto;
background-color: white;
border-collapse: collapse;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
font-size: 16px;
width: 1305px;
}
```

Comment: I think your code should work, how does your table actually render?

Comment: The table doesn't have a problem. I just want to add a scrollbar on top for better accessibility on bigger screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS `transform: rotateX()`. That will rotate `#table_div` and the scrollbar will appear on top of the table.

```css
#table_div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

#myTable td {
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 1305px;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="table_div">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```